# GeoServer 404 error no mapping get in WMTS

Tags: geoserver

I was using a GeoServer tile layer basemap in with OpenLayers.

1. A problem occurred in OpenLayers where the tile area did not appear, so I checked the GeoServer log and saw many logs saying No mapping for GET, but no other error codes were confirmed.
2. It was normally running well, but when the above error occurred logfile location is geoserver/data/logs and the basemap cache data capacity is about 60 GB. Can you tell me why this error occurred?

```
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/openstreet/gwc/service/wmts/openstreet:openstreet
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/openstreet/gwc/service/wmts/openstreet:openstreet
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
   [servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping for GET /geoserver/traffic/gwc/service/wmts
```

OS:CentOS 7.9

GeoServer:2.22.2

Tomcat:Apache Tomcat/9.0.73

Java version: java-11-openjdk-11.0.18.0.10-1.el7_9.x86_6

I dealt with it by turning Tomcat off and on.

Comment: You would need to look earlier in the log file to see what happened

Comment: I checked the geoserver.log in /data/log and the catanina.out file in tomcat/logs, but nothing happened before the error occurred.
Are there cases where it cannot be loaded due to insufficient memory?